# How do you swap bytes/words for a whole buffer I have socket message trying to parse

Tags: java, sockets

I have whole byte buffer of message whose bytes have been word and byte swapped coming across sockets.  I have methods that can do this swapping for 2 shorts or long value. But I was thinking I should really do this on the whole byte array first and then my parsing routines will work. Is there any byte buffere tools for swapping bytes/words for a whole buffer????????????

Comment: Are you sure that your buffer contains only whole words?  Your protocol ensures that?

Comment: Its UDP so I am tring to figure out what the byte swapping is

Comment: Are you trying to convert between a byte[] and a String? You can do that by using getBytes() on a String and instantiating a new String using the byte[].

Comment: I am tryiing to parse a messa that I know has byte an word swapping of some kind. Is its possible to use ByteBuffer and set the order from Little Endian to Big Endian? I am trying to play with this now but no luck yet

Comment: Swapping means different things depending on how many bytes you need to swap. For 1 byte you don't move anything for 2 bytes you need to swap 2 for 4 bytes etc.  This means there is no way to swap all the bytes of a buffer and do something sane.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ByteBuffer.order(endianess)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order-java.nio.ByteOrder-)

```
socket.getChannel().read(byteBuffer); // More or less

byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
```

This will use LSB or MSB first (least/most significant byte first). There still are main frames where 4-bytes words have a still different order. But here it should be just what you wanted.

Comment: I tried this and it is not swapping any of the byte ordering. The way my data is coming in is that the each byte of a word is swapped and each word is swapped with another word. Do you know of anything that will do that?

Comment: For good order,  `getShort`, `getInt,` and such still do not work, because of a still different order (like the main frame case I mentioned) **?** Maybe overriding ByteBuffer and doing two getShort for a getInt or other sorcery might help. Sorry.